# How can a `NSLayoutYAxisAnchor` be used as variable?

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint, nslayoutanchor

How can a variable of type `NSLayoutYAxisAnchor` be defined?

The following doesnt work, but hopefully illustrates what I mean:

```
let anAnchor: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor = .topAnchor

NSLayoutConstraints.activate([
   viewA.anAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewB.anAnchor)
])
```

Comment: Yes, but how can you define it as `.topAnchor`? `NSLayoutYAxisAnchor` seems to be a common type for any anchor on the y axis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with the new key path feature of Swift 4:

```
let anAnchor = \UIView.topAnchor
let v1 = UIView(); let v2 = UIView() // just for testing purposes
let constraint = v1[keyPath:anAnchor].constraint(equalTo:v2[keyPath:anAnchor])
// now you can activate the constraint, etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it as a keypath in **Swift 4** like this:

```
let anAnchor = \UIView.topAnchor
```

`.topAnchor` is **not** an enumeration type, it's a *property* for a `UIView`.

Therefore, it is not possible before Swift 4 to set it as a variable.

Comment: What about with a Swift 4 keypath? That's how you make a property reference into a variable